# Using shell script to automate input

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

How can I write a .sh file to automate input? For example I have a simple program that asks for a name and a few other things. I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash

echo alice
echo 5
```

I try to use it like

```
./program < ./file.sh
```

but it seems to take `#!/bin/bash` as input. I am wanting the first input the program takes to be `alice` and then directly after `5` which should terminate the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `command < file` will redirect **content** of `file` to `command`

to redirect `output` from executable (in your case execution of  `file.sh` ) use

```
./file.sh | ./program
```

note that `|` is called pipe

see `man bash` §redirection